# React Native: changing state via external function doesn't rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've created a function as per need to change state only if it's not the same value as before (i.e. toggle if not same). However, it doesn't rerenders the components. Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong? It does change the state though.

```
export function toggleState(thi_s, k, new_v)
{
    if(thi_s.state[k]!=new_v)
    {
        thi_s.state[k] = new_v;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

.
.

[usage]

```
if(this.state.xyz!=true) this.setState({xyz:true}); //does rerender as expected
```

.

```
toggleState(this, 'xyz', true); //doesn't rerenders
```

The state is changed without rerending, and I can check it using `console.log` right after the call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `toggleState` you're not calling `setState` and are mutating the state directly, which you should never do and is also the reason why a re-render is not triggered:

```
thi_s.state[k] = new_v;
```

Change that to

```
thi_s.setState({[k]: new_v});
```

Also, instead of passing `this` to `toggleState` you should consider using an arrow function or `.bind(this)` instead so that you can reference `this` inside of the function w/o passing it as an argument.